# Surjective composed function question

Tags: functions

Given two functions $ f $ and $ g $ such that the composite function $ g o f $ is surjective, with respect to the function $ g $ we can state:

- The function $ g $ is surjective
- The function $ g $ is surjective if $ f $ is surjective
- The function $ g $ can never be surjective
- The problem, as stated, is not conclusive

Can anyone give me a hand where to start, and where to go?

Thanks

Comment: See [Composition and decomposition of Surjective functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) : "The composite of surjective functions is always surjective: If $f$ and $g$ are both surjective, and the codomain of $g$ is equal to the domain of $f$, then $fog$ is surjective. Conversely, if $fog$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective (but $g$, the function applied first, need not be)."

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$ be functions such
that $g\circ f:A\rightarrow C$ is surjective.

Then for each $c\in C$ some $a\in A$ exists with $g\left(f\left(a\right)\right)=c$ showing
immediately that $g$ is surjective.